# GREP to find words contain a substring of 3 consecutive vowels and length is exactly 10

Tags: regex, grep

I want GREP for find the words that are exactly 10 characters long and that contain a substring of 3 consecutive vowels.
And i tried and got this so far,

```
(.*[aeiou]{3}.*){10}
```

It dosent work correctly. So if someone could help me out on this would be great. Thank You.

Comment: Check [`grep -oP '\b(?=\w{10}\b)\w*[aeiou]{3}\w*\b'`](http://ideone.com/hWnEK1)

Answer (score 2):

With `grep` you could use:

```
grep -E "[aeiou]{3}" | grep -E "^.{10}$"
```

or `egrep`:

```
egrep "[aeiou]{3}" | egrep "^.{10}$"
```

`awk` should work also:

```
awk 'length == 10 && /[aouei]{3}/'
```

Comment: awk solution is nice . `grep -E` and `egrep` are actually the same commands typed differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with Perl regular expression (`-P`) in order to use `positive lookahead`

```
grep -P "(?=[a-z0-9]{10}$).*[aeiou]{3}.*" test.txt
```

---

Grep options:

```
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
```

---

[image]

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xPCGhv/3)